# Extracting specific values from a from a text file with long lines

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to get all "CP" values from a log file like below:

```
2013-06-27 17:00:00,017 INFO - [AlertSchedulerThread18] [2013-06-27 16:59:59, 813] -- SN: 989333333333 ||DN: 989333333333 ||CategoryId: 4687 ||CGID: null||Processing started ||Billing started||Billing Process: 97 msec ||Response code: 2001 ||Package id: 4387 ||TransactionId: 66651372336199820989389553437483742||CDR:26 msec||CDR insertion: 135 msec||Successfully inserted in CDR Table||CP:53 msec||PROC - 9 msec||Successfully executed procedure call.||Billing Ended||197 msec ||Processing ended
2013-06-27 17:00:00,018 INFO - [AlertSchedulerThread62] [2013-06-27 16:59:59, 824] -- SN: 989333333333 ||DN: 989333333333 ||CategoryId: 3241 ||CGID: null||Processing started ||Billing started||Billing Process: 61 msec ||Response code: 2001 ||Package id: 2861 ||TransactionId: 666513723361998319893580191324005184||CDR:25 msec||CDR insertion: 103 msec||Successfully inserted in CDR Table||CP:59 msec||PROC - 24 msec||Successfully executed procedure call.||Billing Ended||187 msec ||Processing ended
2013-06-27 17:00:00,028 INFO - [AlertSchedulerThread29] [2013-06-27 16:59:59, 903] -- SN: 989333333333 ||DN: 989333333333 ||CategoryId: 4527 ||CGID: null||Processing started ||Billing started||Billing Process: 47 msec ||Response code: 2001 ||Package id: 4227 ||TransactionId: 666513723361999169893616006323701572||CDR:22 msec||CDR insertion: 83 msec||Successfully inserted in CDR Table||CP:21 msec||PROC - 7 msec||Successfully executed procedure call.||Billing Ended||112 msec ||Processing ended
```

...getting output like this:

```
CP:53 msec
CP:59 msec
CP:21 msec
```

How can I do this using awk?

Comment: Are those `*` really there or did you just add them to highlight the field you are interested in ?

Comment: no, just added to highlight them

Comment: sorry, by putting ** i caused wrong answers.

Answer (score 3):

`cut` is always good and fast for these things:

```
$ cut -d"*" -f3 file
CP:53 msec
CP:59 msec
CP:21 msec
```

Anyway, these `awk` ways can make it:

```
$ awk -F"|" '{print $27}' file  | sed 's/*//g'
CP:53 msec
CP:59 msec
CP:21 msec
```

or

```
$ awk -F"\|\|" '{print $14}' file | sed 's/*//g'
CP:53 msec
CP:59 msec
CP:21 msec
```

Or also

```
$ awk -F"*" '{print $3}' file
CP:53 msec
CP:59 msec
CP:21 msec
```

In both, we set the field delimiter to split the string as some specific character `|` or `*`. Then we print a certain block of the split text.

Comment: Or: `awk '{print $14}' FS='\\|\\|' input`

Comment: Note that prints the stars, which the OP didn't seem to want.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell, didn't know how to make `||` be the delimiter.

Comment: Sure @JohnZwinck, just updated my answer to replace these `*`. Also my last option `-F"*"` gets rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about a hilarious sed command?

```
sed -n 's/.*\*\*\(.*\)\*\*.*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F"[|*]+" '{ print $14 }' file
```

Comment: I like this `-F` expression, did not know it was possible to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[|][|]' '{print $14}' file
**CP:53 msec**

**CP:59 msec**

**CP:21 msec**
```

If you REALLY have '*'s in the input, just tweak to remove them:

```
$ awk -F'[|][|]' '{gsub(/\*/,""); print $14}' file
CP:53 msec

CP:59 msec

CP:21 msec
```

Comment: awk -F'[|][|]' '{print $14}' logActivity.log | grep "CP" > cptimes   
by this i could extract the required values, thanks

Comment: @Mahdi Why are you piping to grep? You never need grep if you're already using awk - if you have input different than you posted and only want lines with "CP" in the 14th field then just specify that in the awk script: `awk -F'[|][|]' '$14~/CP/{gsub(/\*/,""); print $14}' file`

Answer (score 2):

There's always `grep`:

```
grep -o 'CP:[[:digit:]]* msec' log.txt
```

If it's not necessarily going to be msec every time, you can just take everything up to the pipe:

```
grep -o 'CP:[^|]*' log.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
$sed -r 's/.*(CP:[0-9]+\smsec).*/\1/' file
CP:53 msec
CP:59 msec
CP:21 msec
```